# Hitting connection paused fork issues with pymongo cause I need to access to db to configure before multiprocessing starts

Tags: python, mongodb, multiprocessing, pymongo, fork

I've been struggling with this for a couple months now and have tried a lot of different things to try to alleviate but am not sure what to do anymore. All the examples that I see are different than what I need and in my case it just wouldn't work.

To preface the problem, I have processor applications that get spawned by a manager as a docker container. The processor is a single class that gets run in a forever while loop that processes the same list of items over and over again and runs a function on them. The code I'm working with is quite large so I created a smaller version of the problem below.

this is how I create my engine

db.py

```
from os import getpid
from pymongo import MongoClient

_mongo_client = None
_mongo_client_pid = None



def get_mongodb_uri(MONGO_DB_HOST, MONGO_DB_PORT) -> str:
        return 'mongodb://{}:{}/{}'.format(MONGO_DB_HOST, MONGO_DB_PORT, 'taskprocessor')


def get_db_engine():
    global _mongo_client, _mongo_client_pid
    curr_pid = getpid()
    if curr_pid != _mongo_client_pid:
        _mongo_client = MongoClient(get_mongodb_uri(), connect=False)
        _mongo_client_pid = curr_pid
    return _mongo_client



def get_db(name):
    return get_db_engine()['taskprocessor'][name]
```

These are my DB models
processor.py

```
from uuid import uuid4
from taskprocessor.db import get_db


class ProcessorModel():
    db = get_db("processors")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.uid = kwargs.get('uid', str(uuid4()))
        self.exceptions = kwargs.get('exceptions', [])
        self.to_process = kwargs.get('to_process', [])
        self.functions = kwargs.get('functions', ["int", "round"])

    def save(self):
        return self.db.insert_one(self.__dict__).inserted_id is not None

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, uid):
        res = cls.db.find_one(dict(uid=uid))
        return ProcessorModel(**res)
```

result.py

```
from uuid import uuid4
from taskprocessor.db import get_db


class ResultModel():
    db = get_db("results")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.uid = kwargs.get('uid', str(uuid4()))
        self.res = kwargs.get('res', dict())

    def save(self):
        return self.db.insert_one(self.__dict__).inserted_id is not None
```

And my main.py that gets started as a docker container
to run a forever loop

```
import os
from time import sleep
from taskprocessor.db.processor import ProcessorModel
from taskprocessor.db.result import ResultModel
from multiprocessing import Pool


class Processor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = os.getenv("PROCESSOR_ID")
        self.db_model = ProcessorModel.get(self.id)
        self.to_process = self.db_model.to_process  # list of floats [1.23, 1.535, 1.33499, 242.2352, 352.232]
        self.functions = self.db_model.functions  # list i.e ["round", "int"]

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                pool = Pool(2)
                res = list(pool.map(self.analyse, self.to_process))
                print(res)
                sleep(100)
            except Exception as e:
                self.db_model = ProcessorModel.get(os.getenv("PROCESSOR_ID"))
                self.db_model.exceptions.append(f"exception {e}")
                self.db_model.save()
                print("Exception")

    def analyse(self, item):
        res = {}
        for func in self.functions:
            if func == "round":
                res['round'] = round(item)
            if func == "int":
                res['int'] = int(item)
        ResultModel(res=res).save()

        return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Processor()
    p.run()
```

I've tried setting connect=False, or even trying to close the connection after the configuration but then end up with `connection closed` errors. I also tried using a system of recognizing the PID and giving a different client but that still did not help.

Almost all examples I see are where the DB access is not needed before the multiprocessing fork. In my case the initial configuration is heavy and cannot be efficient to do every single time in the process loop. Furthermore the items to process themselves depends on the data from the DB.

I can live with not being able to save the exceptions to the db object from the main pid.

I'm seeing the error logs around fork safety as well as hitting connection pool paused errors as as symptom of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody sees this, I was using pymongo 4.0.2 and upgraded to 4.3.3 and not seeing the errors I was previously seeing.